# Merge and combine item into array based on property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge an object into an array. Based on the title of the object, if it already exists in the array I want to add the amount of the object into the existing amount.

For example:

```
let items = [{"title":"x","amount":1}, {"title":"y","amount":1}, {"title":"z","amount":1}];
let obj1 = {"title":"x","amount":2};
```

If obj1 is merged into items the expected output would be

```
[{"title":"x","amount":3}, {"title":"y","amount":1}, {"title":"z","amount":1}]
```

Here is the solution I've come up with so far, Its working but I feel like there has to be a more elegant solution out there.

```
mergeResponses(x){
    var found = this.items.some(function (arr) {
        return arr.title === x.title;
    });
    if(!found){
        //item doesnt exist, add to array
        this.items.push(x);
    }else{
        //item already exists, add amount to existing amount
        let dupItem = this.items.find(function (y) {
            return y.title == x.title;
        });
        dupItem.amount += x.amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is OK. You only need to remove the logic of the `dupItem` variable and make the find with the other variable (`found`), so, just remove that and replace `dupItem` by `found`.

Comment: @ElChiniNet No, because `found` does not refer to the item. It holds a boolean that indicates whether or not such item exists.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, that is the reason of this part of my comment: _You only need to remove the logic of the `dupItem` variable and **make the find** with the other variable (`found`)_. English is not my native language, I don't know if it is not understood.

Comment: @ElChiniNet Sorry, your comment was a little hard to follow. After re-reading it, I see that it's indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks, I still make a lot of mistakes with my English so I always hesitate if something is well written or not ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a direct translation of your requirements. It's slightly more elegant than your implementation in the sense that the lookup only needs to be performed once.

```js
let items = [{"title":"x","amount":1}, {"title":"y","amount":1}, {"title":"z","amount":1}];
let item = {"title":"x","amount":2};

let existing = items.find(i => i.title === item.title);

if (existing) {
  existing.amount += item.amount;
} else {
  items.push(item);
}

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this also,I don't say that this the better way but this also one way to do this.

```
var xyz=items.find(function(item){
if(item.title==obj1.title)
    return item;
});

if(xyz)
   xyz.amount+=obj1.amount;
else
   items.push(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as :

```
   var items = [{"title":"x","amount":1}, {"title":"y","amount":1}, {"title":"z","amount":1}];
var obj = {"title":"x","amount":3};

matches = _.filter(items, i => i.title === obj.title)
if (matches) {
    _.forEach (
        matches,
        match => match.amount += obj.amount
    )
} else {
    items.push(obj)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(items))
```

Comment: First of all, you should mention that your solution requires lodash or underscore.js. Second, if you do decide to pull in lodash or underscore.js, you can write a far more elegant implementation than this one.